# In Oracle, how do you search a tables' column-names?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a large table with over 50 columns. And I would like to search those columns for a particular word. How do I do this in Oracle ?

thanks

Comment: A word in the column name, or a word in the data of one of the columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='your_table_name' and COLUMN_NAME like '%whatever_word_required%';
```

Explanation: `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` describes the columns of the tables, views, and clusters accessible to the current user. So from all the tables, since you want to search in a particular table so give your `table-name` in the query and specify the criteria for columns using the `LIKE`.

Say if your table name is `"Table1"` and column-name you are trying to search is `"Employee"`, so the query becomes:

```
select COLUMN_NAME from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME='Table1' and COLUMN_NAME like '%Employee%';
```

For reference see the [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm)